# Linker command failed with exit code 1 with Google Sign In

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, google-signin

I'm using Google Sign-in for my iOS application. This is in Xcode 7.  I followed all the instructions on the website.  I did pod init, put `pod 'Google/SignIn'` in the Podfile, ran pod install, downloaded the configuration file and dragged it into the project, put the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID in URL Schemes of into.plist.  I put everything into AppDelegate.m.  I am also using Facebook sign in so instead of what they told me I put this in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation] || [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                                                                                 sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                                                                        annotation:annotation];
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-APP_NAME
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried adding $(PROJECT_DIR) to Framework Search Paths and marking it recursive, but that didn't work.  Anyone know what could be going on?

Edit: When I run `pod install` I see the following messages:

```
[!] The `Piste [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Piste/Pods-Piste.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Piste [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Piste/Pods-Piste.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning your project. If this does not work try running pod install one more time. Also, remember to only use .xcworkspace when running projects with cocoapods.

Comment: Wow, that's it.  I was looking at the .xcproj file.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is really hard to tell without messing around with the project, at least in my experiences.

First of all, do you get any warnings when you pod install? Not red errors, but yellow warnings. If so, try correcting those first. I had two separate projects with similar warnings. One project ran fine if I ignored the warning, and the other would not. In this specific case, I had to apply the $(inherited) tag for each of the targets in build settings. Y

Also, cleaning the project (CMD + SHIFT + K) in between these pod/build setting changes can be helpful.

Let me know if you have any warnings/pod install errors.

Comment: Ah, you may be onto something.  Check my edit.  Any idea how to fix those?

Comment: Click on the target (little blue icon) with your project/target name. If you only have your project and your pods, you should have one that is your project name and one that just says "Pods". From there, you should be able to see different tabs regarding your project (General, Resource Tags, Build Settings, etc.). Use the search bar to find framework search paths. Expand it (little black arrow to the left of "framework search paths". Either clear out each one individually, or add the $(inherited) tag for each of them. I would try clearing them out first.

Comment: The problem is though I already have `/Users/jfarkerson/Documents/FacebookSDK` in there so I can't clear it out.  Adding $(inherited) doesn't work either.  When I add $(inherited), the warnings do go away though.  It just still doesn't compile.